# how to execute mongo admin command from java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java

I want to execute soem admin command with parameters from java.

The commands are:

```
{ enablesharding : "test" }
{ shardcollection : "test.test_collection", key : {"number":1} }
```

How can I do it from java driver?

The following code doesn't works:

```
mongo.getDb("admin").command("{shardcollection : \"test.test_collection\", key:\"number\":1} }")
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just found it

```
DB db = mongo.getDB("admin");
DBObject cmd = new BasicDBObject();
cmd.put("shardcollection", "testDB.x");
cmd.put("key", new BasicDBObject("userId", 1));
CommandResult result = db.command(cmd);
```

Comment: This answer was useful for me. I'll just point that I needed to connect to a `mongos`, a simple `mongod` is not enough. It may be obvious but I didn't saw it here explicitly.

Comment: `mongo.getDb("admin").runCommand` would have been more intuitive.

Answer (score 10):

I just want to add that Julias's answer is correct, but now it's deprecated.
You could use new API (`Document` class is from package  `org.bson`):

```
MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("admin");
Document documentA = database.runCommand(new Document("enablesharding", "test"));
Document documentB = database.runCommand(
        new Document("shardcollection", "testDB.x").append("key", new Document("userId", 1)));
```

Comment: How can you tell if the return Document was successful or not? The CommandResult has an OK method on it. Document does not

Answer (score -1):

Have you ensured you have authenticated to the db successfully?

Have you tried db.eval(COMMAND_THAT_YOU_WANT_TO_EVAL);

Comment: db.eval() has two arguments. I do not know what Objects... args should be

Comment: You might want to take a closer look @Julias.  The second argument is a variable length argument list; this means is can be zero or more arguments.

Comment: Keep in mind this does not work in sharded environments